# iOS Push Notification showing invalid token

Tags: apple-push-notifications, javapns

I have been facing this invalid token when I test the iOS push notification. 
It works fine if I build the project in development mode. 
This are the following I used to create certificate. 
1. I generate certSigningRequest and saved. 
2. Generate all development, adhoc, distribution certificate and provisioning profiles. 
3. Test in development works fine. 
4. Archive in Adhoc mode and installed the app. Now fail to push by showing invalid token. enter image description here

[image: Code signing image]

[image: Easy APNs Provider test image]

Please suggest some help, I have been trying many days but still no solution.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Guys there is one update, 
If I choose the server as gateway.push.apple.com, it works fine. 
[Success image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbDZq.png)